# How to set a binary secret value from the CLI for AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

How do I set a binary value on a secret in AWS Secrets Manager using the CLI?

The [docs say](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/put-secret-value.html):

> `--secret-binary (blob)`
>
> (Optional) Specifies binary data that you want to encrypt and store in the new version of the secret. To use this parameter in the command-line tools, we recommend that you store your binary data in a file and then use the appropriate technique for your tool to pass the contents of the file as a parameter.

I have tried the following:

```
$ V=$(cat mykeystore.jks)
$ aws secretsmanager put-secret-value --secret-id xxx --secret-binary "$V"
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found it:

```
aws secretsmanager put-secret-value --secret-id xxx --secret-binary fileb://mykeystore.jks
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.

Comment: the `fileb://` part is gold.

Answer (score 7):

The self-authored answer from OP covers how to set the value of an existing secret to a file binary. I wanted to add the way to use a file binary when creating an entirely new secret:

```
aws secretsmanager create-secret --name xxx --secret-binary fileb://mykeystore.jks
```